# Are the /lib/modules/modules.dep all contained in /lib/modules/XXX?

Tags: module, linux-kernel

Is there any module from `/lib/modules/modules.dep` that is NOT contained in `/lib/modules/'uname -r'` ? More precisely : if we don't pay attention to the kernel's version, can it happen ?

Comment: `modules.dep` file is created either when you build kernel and install its modules, or enforced manually when you run `moddep -a` tool. The list of dependencies is completely based on kernel version and contents of */lib/modules/<kversion>/` folder. And in some weird cases it would be possible that module is absent in the folder (corrupted / deleted file).

Comment: If `modules.dep` is created when we build the kernel and install modules, in which cases should we update it with `depmod -a` ? + so your answer is "yes" ?

Comment: 1. In obvious case when you add/remove module (don't forget that one may add extra module compiled out-of-tree). 2. Practically yes, the answer is "yes", though as I mentioned there is no 100% guarantee.